# Descending order sort for very small numbers

Tags: linux, sorting

I have my input file as :

```
Helguson 1.11889675673e-06
CAPTION_spot 1.37407731642e-07
Earning 1.20657023177e-06
340km 6.82228429758e-07
Mortimer 3.08700799033e-07
yellow 6.26784196571e-06
four 0.000271117940104
Pronk 5.79848408861e-07
jihad 3.25632057648e-07
```

I want to sort in descending order of the second column and hence, I tried using the linux command:

```
sort -k2 -nr input.txt > output.txt
```

My output is generated as:

```
340km 6.82228429758e-07
yellow 6.26784196571e-06
Pronk 5.79848408861e-07
jihad 3.25632057648e-07
Mortimer 3.08700799033e-07
CAPTION_spot 1.37407731642e-07
Earning 1.20657023177e-06
Helguson 1.11889675673e-06
four 0.000271117940104
```

It is not sorting properly. How to resolve this? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the -g option in sort. Otherwise it sorts in alphanumeric order, but with -g it converts it to a number first and then sorts.

Comment: I had not run across a need for that option in 20 years (I had never had the need to sort numbers in scientific notation) Old dog learned a new trick -- thanks.